# Recursive search for a node in non-binary tree

Tags: java, search, tree

I want to search for an item in non-binary tree (any node can have n - children) and exit from recursion immediately. The node in question can be any node, not only leafs.

This is my code but i don't get complete search.

```
private nNode recursiveSearch(data gi,nNode node){
        if (node.getdata()==gi)
            return node;
        nNode[] children = node.getChildren(); 
        if (children.length>0)
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {         
            return recursiveSearch(gi, children[i]);
        }
        return null;
 }
```

nNode contains :

`ArrayList mChildren ;` (it's children)
and data object.

Comment: What does your `nNode` look like?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You shouldn't exit after exploring the first child. You don't need the `if` statement in front of the `for` loop.

```
private nNode recursiveSearch(data gi,nNode node){
    if (node.getdata()==gi)
        return node;
    nNode[] children = node.getChildren(); 
    nNode res = null;
    for (int i = 0; res == null && i < children.length; i++) {         
        res = recursiveSearch(gi, children[i]);
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Comment: isn't this looping more than it should? I mean if the node is found in the for loop at step i < children.length - 1, the for loop will still continue to call recursiveSearch, or no? And this might be on multiple nested levels.

Comment: Sergey, note that the requirement is to find ONE (I guess the first found) element, not ALL

Answer (score 8):

In your code if recursiveSearch(gi, children[i]) returned null then i+1 not searched, modify:

```
private nNode recursiveSearch(data gi,nNode node){
        if (node.getdata()==gi)
            return node;
        nNode[] children = node.getChildren(); 
        nNode temp;
        if (children.length>0)
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {         
            temp = recursiveSearch(gi, children[i]);
            if(temp!=null)
                return temp;
        }
        return null;
 }
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer cause it doesn't search for no reason after it finds it, by interrupting the loop