# How to get depth of a node in one recursive search in non-binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, recursion, tree

According to [Recursive search for a node in non-binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617790/recursive-search-for-a-node-in-non-binary-tree), I know how to achieve the recursive search but how can I get the depth of this node?

I think I should add a counter for every recursion but I have no idea where I should add this counter.....

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the partial code with comments:

```
public class Tree
{
    private Node root;

    public int findDepth(int searchNodeValue) {
        List<Node> nodesAtCurrentLevel = Collections.singletonList(root);

        return recursiveSearch(0, searchNodeValue, nodesAtCurrentLevel);
    }

    public int recursiveSearch(int level, int searchNodeValue, List<Node> nodesAtCurrentLevel) {
        List<Node> nodesAtNextLevel = new ArrayList<Node>();

        // Check if searchNode matches any node at current level
        for (Node node : nodesAtCurrentLevel) {
            // If it matches, we have found the node, return current level
            if (node.getValue() == searchNodeValue) {
                return level;
            }

            // Add children of all nodes at current level in nodesAtNextLevel
            if (node.hasChildren()) {
                nodesAtNextLevel.addAll(node.getChildren());
            }
        }

        // searchNode is not found at current level, increment level and continue search at next level if next level exists in tree
        if (!nodesAtNextLevel.isEmpty()) {
            return recursiveSearch(level + 1, searchNodeValue, nodesAtNextLevel);
        }

        // We have traversed entire tree. Node not found. Return -1
        return -1;
    }
}

class Node
{
    private int value;

    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public Node(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean hasChildren() {
        return children.isEmpty();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited

-- Have the recursion function get a input level. Start with 0/-1. Return a object; the object has the node AND the level. Each pass of recursion function increments the passed in level and sets that in the return object.

-- Pass in the level to recursion function. Start it at 0/-1. Maintain a global variable (or a variable that is defined non local to the function so that the same variable is accessed on each iteration of the function; i.e. the variable is NOT on stack but on heap. I hope this thing is trivial to do in Java and does NOT require further explanation). Set it to (1 + passed in level) at beginning of recursion function. This would NOT be thread safe.

// the original answer had the idea to pass in the level as reference and increment it inside the recursion function. Apparently that is tedious to do in Java.

Comment: "pass along a variable by reference" - you know the question is about Java right? (I know it's possible to simulate pass-by-reference in Java, but a mention of pass-by-reference should go together with an explanation and/or link)

Comment: ok. Deleted the pass by reference bit. Replaced with something else.