# Java : Recursively Iterating over a map

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

We have an object that looks like a "recursive" datastructure.

Let's assume we have a Person object whose structure is like this

```
public class Person {
    private String id;

    private Map<String,Person> persons;

    public Person(String id, Map<String,Person> persons){
        this.id = id;
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Map<String, Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(Map<String, Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", persons=" + persons + "]";
    }

}
```

An example representation of this object would be : (sample data)

```
  Person p1 = new Person("Jim", ImmutableMap.of("A001",new Person("Mike",ImmutableMap.of("D001",new Person("Jack",ImmutableMap.of("E001",new Person("Kim",null))))),
                                                         "Z001",new Person("Adam",ImmutableMap.of("Y001",new Person("Eve",ImmutableMap.of("X001",new Person("Dave",null)))))));
```

Note 1 : `ImmutableMap` is from google guava collection

Note 2: Let's assume the 'key' for the Map in the Person object is name of the person.

**Given a name of the person, what is the most efficient way to go iterate and get the id.**  ?

For example, if input is 'Eve', the output should ne 'Y001'

Comment: Are you allowed to have cycles where people have each other in their `persons` maps, either directly or indirectly?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using Guava, consider adding a method like this to the `Person` class:

```
public FluentIterable<Map.Entry<String, Person>> tree() {
    if (persons == null)
        return FluentIterable.from(ImmutableList.of());
    return FluentIterable.from(persons.entrySet())
            .transformAndConcat(
                entry -> Iterables.concat(ImmutableList.of(entry), entry.getValue().tree()));
}
```

Or if you cannot use Java-8:

```
public FluentIterable<Map.Entry<String, Person>> tree() {
    if (persons == null)
        return FluentIterable.from(ImmutableList.of());
    return FluentIterable.from(persons.entrySet())
        .transformAndConcat(
            new Function<Entry<String, Person>, Iterable<Entry<String, Person>>>() {
            @Override
            public Iterable<Map.Entry<String, Person>> apply(
                    Map.Entry<String, Person> entry) {
                return Iterables.concat(ImmutableList.of(entry), entry.getValue().tree());
            }
        });
}
```

It will flatten the tree of all persons into single `Iterable` which can be easily used either in for-loop:

```
String name = "Eve";
for(Map.Entry<String, Person> e : p1.tree()) {
    if(e.getValue().getId().equals(name)) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
        break;
    }
}
```

Or with the `FluentIterable` operations:

```
System.out.println(p1.tree()
                     .firstMatch(e -> e.getValue().getId().equals(name))
                     .get().getKey());
```

Comment: You know `TreeTraverser` already does most of this work for you?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, don't worry, I already upvoted your answer :-) It's not much shorter than mine, but indeed using dedicated feature is better. Note however that OP actually needs Entry keys as well, so your answer does not actually solves his problem. Probably you should edit it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect job for Guava's `TreeTraverser`:

```
Iterable<Person> allPersons = new TreeTraverser<Person>() {
  @Override public Iterable<Person> children(Person p) {
     return p.getPersons().values();
  }
}.preOrderTraversal(rootPerson);
for (Person p : allPersons) {
  if (p.getId().equals(id)) {
    return p;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is a type of tree in reality. So you can use standard method of sorting trees. If you tree were a binary tree (it appears this isn't) you might be able to make this very efficiently.

The below will work, but I don't have proof that it is the most efficient method. Non-binary trees mostly just have to be plugged away at.

Efficiency depends on how high you think the recursiveness will be stacked. If you think that most structures will be like the sample structure, that is: very deep, but only a few persons per level, this will be quite efficent. Especially if your result will be near the bottom.

```
public String iterate(String name) {
        if (persons != null) {
            for (Entry<String, Person> entry : persons.entrySet()) {
                Person value = entry.getValue();
                if (value.getId().equals(name)) {
                    return entry.getKey(); //Since the key of each map is the ID when they return the key
                } else {
                    String ans = value.iterate(name);
                    if (ans != null) {
                        return ans;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It quickly moves through a whole stack of person lists without having to return to the top.

However if you have a wide setup, and you think your values will mostly be near the top you could use something like the following.

```
public String iterate(String name) {
        if (persons != null) {
            for (Entry<String, Person> entry : persons.entrySet()) {
                Person value = entry.getValue();
                if (value.getId().equals(name)) {
                    return entry.getKey(); //Since the key of each map is the ID when they return the key
                }
            }

            for (Entry<String, Person> entry : persons.entrySet()) {
                String ans = entry.getValue().iterate(name);
                if (ans != null) {
                    return ans;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This will allow quick finding of something near the top of your structure but will be slower to find a person at the bottom of your structure.

I'm guessing you will want the upper solution, it's the more standard. However, I don't think there's a huge difference between them. For another version of it, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617790/recursive-search-for-a-node-in-non-binary-tree) about traversing trees.